# Change logo on Hybris through addon

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am new to Hybris and i want to change the logo of Hybris OOTB (PowerTools). But this i wanna do it through my new created addon.
I discover that in this impex file (cm-content_en.impex) i have this

```
# Site Logo Component
UPDATE SimpleBannerComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];$picture[lang=$lang]
;;SiteLogoComponent;/images/default_logo.svg
```

Now, i wanna add my custom logo svg which is located in

```
/companystorefrontaddon/acceleratoraddon/web/webroot/_ui/responsive/common/images/new_logo.svg
```

How can i add the path to my impex file?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, put your image (.svg) under : `powertoolsstore\resources\powertoolsstore\import\sampledata\contentCatalogs\powertoolsContentCatalog\images\theme\`.
2. Then, next create a `Media` with the code `my_default_logo.svg` using this `impex` :

```xml
## in : cms-content.impex

$contentCatalog=powertoolsContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]
$media=media(code, $contentCV);

$siteResource=jar:de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.constants.PowertoolsStoreConstants&/powertoolsstore/import/sampledata/contentCatalogs/$contentCatalog

INSERT_UPDATE Media;$contentCV[unique=true];code[unique=true];realfilename;@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator];mime[default='image/jpeg'];altText;folder(qualifier)[default='images']
;  ;my_default_logo.svg  ;default_logo.svg ;$siteResource/images/theme/default_logo.svg ;image/png; ;
```

**Note** : that this variable `$siteResource` refers to `powertoolsstore\resources\powertoolsstore\import\sampledata\contentCatalogs\powertoolsContentCatalog\`.

3. And finally attach the new created `Media` to the `SiteLogoComponent` :

```xml
## in : cms-content_en.impex

$lang=en
$contentCatalog=powertoolsContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]
$picture=media(code, $contentCV);

INSERT_UPDATE SimpleBannerComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];$picture[lang=$lang]
;;SiteLogoComponent; my_default_logo.svg
```

**Note** : that you need to update `cms-content_fr.impex` and `cms-content_de.impex` and all other languages too.

4. You should run a **Synchronization** of the **Powertools Content Catalog** (from : **Staged** to **Online**) otherwise you wont be able to see the changes in the front.

Comment: Thanks, very useful info.

Comment: Is it best practice to change media file from backoffice or just import impex from hac. Which is which? @Mouad EL Fakir